# Blow up and finished/glued desingularization

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup

My interest is in the "finished product", the desingularization $\tilde{X}$ of a variety (or scheme) $X$. It is widely described how to get to the different resolved charts but not how they glue together.

I think I understood that if I find an isomorphism between two exceptional divisors, I can glue the charts via this isomorphism. I just do not understand how I could find this isomorphism, or how I know they are the same. I'm working in the embedded case. My understanding so far:

**Case 1:** Take the variety $X=V(x^2-y^3)$. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_of_singularities) shows an image of the non-resolved charts and one final chart. That's enough because we don't have any new information in the other charts about the exceptional divisors.

**Case 2:** Say, we have the variety $V(x^2+y^2-z^3)$. Blow it up to get chart 1 and 2 (both resolved) and chart 3 with exceptional divisor $D$ from the first blowup. Get charts 3.1, 3.2 and 3.3 (3.3 resolved) with exceptional divisors $D$ and $E$ in both non-resolved charts from blowing up chart 3. Now we blow both of these up in their center $D \cap E$. Since the blowup is determined by its center, we know that the resulting divisors must be isomorphic, although I don't know how to compute or glue that explicitly.

**Case 3** We have a variety where the same exceptional divisor appears in different blowups, i. e. there are two charts with isomorphic centers, without it being so "obvious". We could use the previous example, assuming that we don't see that it's both $D \cap E$. I have done the following *calculations for attaining the charts*:

- Variety $V(x^2+y^2-z^3)$. Use variables $(x,y,z,u:v:w)$, blowing up in $(0,0,0)$.
- Get chart 3 $(w=1)$ via $y=zv, x=zu$:$V(u^2+v^2-z)$ and $D=V(z)$. Next, use variables $(u,v,z,r:s:t)$, blowing up in $(0,0,0)$.
- Get chart 3.1 $(r=1)$ via $v=us,z=ut$: $V(u+us^2-t)$ and $\tilde{D}=V(t)$, $E=V(u)$ and center $V(u,t)$.
- Get chart 3.2 $(s=1)$ via $z=vt, u=vr$: $V(vr^2+v-t)$ and $\tilde{D}=V(t)$ and $E=V(v)$ with center $V(t,v)$ for the following blowup.

I appreciate any help!

**Direct calculation - is that correct and sufficient?**

Let $U_{31}$ be the affine chart 3.1 with exceptional divisors $D_{31}$ and $E_{31}$ and coordinates $(u,v,z,s,t)$, same with 3 and 3.2.

$$\pi_{31}: U_{31} \rightarrow U_{3}: (u,v,z,s,t) = (u,us,ut,s,t) \mapsto (u,s,t)$$

which gives us the following map for the center $C_{31}=V(u,t)$:

$$\pi_{31}(C_{31})=\pi_{31}(V(u,t))=\pi_{31}(\{(0,v,z,s,0)\})=\{(0,r,0)\}$$

as well as, for the other chart,

$$\pi_{32}: U_{32} \rightarrow U_{3}: (u,v,z,r,t) = (vr,v,vt,r,t) \mapsto (v,r,t), C_{32}=\{(0,v,z,s,0)\} \mapsto \{(0,s,0)\}$$

Now, $\{(0,r,0)\}$ and $\{(0,s,0)\}$ are isomorphic in $U_{3}$. But that's the same for points that are not the same under isomorphism?

Comment: The idea here is that blowing up commutes with localization. You should be able to check this from the definition of the blow up of the ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}$ as $\underline{\operatorname{Proj}}(\bigoplus_{n=0} \mathcal{I}^n)$. (A minor other comment: please use x^2 to produce $x^2$ instead of the superscripted character you were using before - it's much easier to read. I've fixed it this post, so the warning is for the future.)

Comment: To give a geometric alternative to the previous comment: let $\pi$ denote the blowup map. Any two charts of the original (irreducible) scheme overlap in a dense open set $U$ along which they glue. If you delete the center of the blowup, you still have a dense open $V \subset U$ which is isomorphic to the open obtained by deleting the exceptional divisor from $\pi^{-1}(U)$. If you track all of this, the isomorphism gluing $\pi^{-1}(V)$ between the two charts should extend to an isomorphism between the copies of the exceptional divisor.

Comment: Thanks a lot, KReiser, for your edit and comment on how to check isomorphy using the Proj construction. At the moment I am still struggling with this notation and want to understand the (seemingly) more straight-forward approach first, so I'm trying to use what Tabes Bridges provided; thank you very much, too, for adding another useful perspective! This try leads me to the calculations I edited into the original post. I'll try to check the Proj construction afterwards. Would that be the right way to do it?